# node js function onWrite is not working properly in google cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this node js function that attempts to update Algolia index once a add/update/delete is done to node Listings

```
exports.indexlisting_algolia = 
    functions.database.ref('/Listings/{listingId}').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
   const index = algolia.initIndex('Listings');
   // var firebaseObject = snapshot.data;
   var firebaseObject = snapshot.data.val();
   console.log("test ",firebaseObject)

   firebaseObject.objectID = context.params.listingId;


  return index.saveObject(firebaseObject).then(
  () => 
   snapshot.data.adminRef.parent.child('last_index_timestamp').set(
      Date.parse(event.timestamp)));
  });
```

this is my error thraceback

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
>       at exports.indexlisting_algolia.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:807:40)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
>       at next (native)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>       at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

line 807 is this function

```
var firebaseObject = snapshot.data.val();
```

what am I doing wrongly and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an old version of the API exposed by the firebase-functions module.  The new one requires that you accept a [`Change`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object, with `before` and `after` attributes, as the first parameter of onWrite and onUpdate triggers.  Those attributes will be DataSnapshot objets.  Your code is currently expecting a DataDeltaSnapshot, which is what you got in the beta version before the full 1.0 release.  This is now deprecated.

You can read about the [API changes in version 1.0 in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).

Please also see the [documentation for database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) for examples.

Your function should look more like this:

```
exports.indexlisting_algolia = 
    functions.database.ref('/Listings/{listingId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const before = change.before;  // snapshot before the update
        const after = change.after;    // snapshot after the update
        const before_data = before.val();
        const afater_data = after.val();
    })
```